# Debugging into function calls

Tags: debugging, raku, rakudo

I want to know if, in this code,

```
sub might-sink {
    return [1,2,Failure.new("boo!"),"still here"];
}

might-sink;
say might-sink;
```

the first call to `might-sink` in [sink context](https://docs.perl6.org/language/contexts) actually calls [`List.sink`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/sink#(List)_method_sink), that is, does nothing. My hunch is that it does, but I'm not sure if that's the case or it's simply not [reified](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#index-entry-Reify), so the failure is not thrown until later.
I have tried the [debugging options here](https://docs.perl6.org/programs/01-debugging), but none of them gets into the code called from this one. So two questions, separated but related:

1. How can I debug into those functions using the Perl 6 debugger or a module?
2. How can I find out if that `List.sink` is actually called or, in general, if `sink` is called when an object finds itself in sink context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if you explicitly called `.sink` on that return value, the `Failure` would not blow up:

```
sub might-sink {
    return [1,2,Failure.new("boo!"),"still here"];
}

might-sink.sink;
say "Did not explode";
# OUTPUT: Did not explode
```

The explosion in your code happens during rendition of `.gist` during `say` call which goes through first 100 elements of your `Array` and calls `.gist` on them. When it does so on the `Failure` element, it detonates it.

You're conflating sinking the list object itself and sinking individual values it contains. You correctly mentioned `List.sink` is a no-op, but `Seq.sink` consumes itself¹, yet it won't explode either, because just the `Seq` is being sunk, not its individual elements: `(+"a", 42).Seq.sink`

If you want to force potential `Failure` explosions, you could:

**1:** [`use fatal`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/pragmas#index-entry-fatal-fatal). This will cause the compiler to fatalize failures, causing their detonation in many places where `Failures` are passed around. This is a lexical pragma and it's also automatically enabled in `try {}` blocks.

```
use fatal;
sub might-sink {
    return [1,2,Failure.new("boo!"),"still here"];
}
might-sink;

# OUTPUT:
# boo!
#  in block <unit> at
```

**2:** Hyper over `.self` method call. It's provided by `Mu` (so is inherited by all objects) and simply returns `self`, so it's a no-op (other than doing a [decont](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2017/12/02/#theoneandonly)). However, since most methods called on armed `Failure` cause them to detonate, calling `.self` on them will cause them to blow up.

```
sub might-sink {
    return [1,2,Failure.new("boo!"),"still here"];
}
might-sink».self;

# OUTPUT:
# boo!
#  in block <unit> at
```

> How can I debug into those functions using the Perl 6 debugger or a module?

Don't use debuggers myself, but `perl6-debug-m` should come preinstalled with your Rakudo installation. It requires you install [`Debugger::UI::CommandLine`](https://modules.perl6.org/repo/Debugger::UI::CommandLine) module. And you just use that instead of `perl6` to run your program and it should offer some instructions on the command line on what it does. There's also a [blog post on it](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/a-perl-6-debugger/) and [a video](http://electure-ms.studiumdigitale.uni-frankfurt.de/vod/clips/mako67J3Gj/flash.html) (requires Flash to play).

There's also a recently-released, alpha-quality [`App::MoarVM::Debug`](https://github.com/edumentab/p6-app-moarvm-debug#appmoarvmdebug) that lets you debug programs even remotely. Its beauty is it lets you dump object guts and navigate them while program is running, so if you can bear with its interface, it can be handy.

Personally, I debug by just using [`dd`](https://docs.perl6.org/programs/01-debugging#index-entry-dd) routine to dump stuff out in strategic points and see if it contains the things I expect it to contains.

> How can I find out if that List.sink is actually called or, in general, if sink is called when an object finds itself in sink context?

You can mix-in a role using `does` or `but` operators that provides a `sink` method that does something you can watch. Like print something:

```
sub foo {
    return [<a b c>] does role { 
        method sink { say "sink called" }
    }
}
foo
# OUTPUT: sink called
```

A more advanced method would be dumping post-optimization [QAST tree](https://perl6.party/post/Perl-6-Core-Hacking-QASTalicious) and seeing if it contains the calls you expect it to. [`CoreHackers::Q`](https://github.com/zoffixznet/q) module makes the dumped QAST tree easier to visualize.

P.S.: on the topic of implied sinkage, it's worth noting [R#1571](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1571) that enumerates several bugs with it and proposes the internal systems handling sinkage be redesigned entirely.

---

¹ - more accurately, `Seq.sink` calls [`.sink-all`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterator#method_sink-all) on its `Iterator`, which by default does simply consume the values, but custom iterators can override that method to be a no-op too.